# How to add camera behind popup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-camera-intent

I have an app when I scan a barcode automatically it will open a popup with some informations.
But my problem is I don't know how to put camera behind popup, something like this in the photo?
Thank you
[image]

Comment: why you want to put camera?

Comment: i want to add camera cause i have a project like that

Comment: you mean you want an overlay over the photo?

Comment: You have to customize the camera using camera2 api or old camera api

Comment: please i want something when i scan a barcode automatically it will open a popup with information... when that popup is open behind that popup i want to put a camera ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)
It is a demo application for using Camera 2 API. You have to customize it according to your needs.

You can achieve the same in image uploaded by you can be done by making a custom dialog layout and show after capturing image.

Comment: Thank u... i download it i will see it , and i will let u know if i need this 
thanks again